# Laravel send data with view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with a Laravel for a school project and I'm haing osme difficulties solving this problem. The code is exactly what I got from another script and I already double checked the code.

**Function Code:**

```
$modules = Module::all();
$id = Auth::user()->id;

$array = array();

foreach($modules as $module) {

  $questions = Question::where('m_id', $module['id'])->count();
  $answers = Answer::where('m_id', $module['id'])->where('user_id', $id)->where('correct', 1)->count();

  $percentage = ($answers / $questions) * 100;

  array_push($array, array(
    'name' => $module->name,
    'description' => $module->description,
    'precentage' => $percentage
  ));
}

print_r($array);

return View::make('hello')->with('modules', $array);
```

In the print_r($array) function I'm getting exactly everything that I want to get in the view. But the problem is that I don't get anything with me, I'm checking it with {{ Session::has('modules') }} and it returns false (not set).

Any solution to this?

Comment: Where is this function located...??

Comment: Try this: print_r(Input::get('modules'));

Comment: this function is located in HomeController, but don't really see why that makes a diffrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you checking for the `modules` key in Session?  You're not setting it in session, you're returning that data with the view.  You should be able to do something like this in your view given the code above:

```
@foreach($modules as $module)
    {{ $module['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

In order for `Session::has('modules')` to return true, you would need to do something like this before you return the view:

```
Session::put('modules', $array);
```

Comment: Yea okey true, men the foreach method does not work, i have tried sevral things to get the data out.

*EDIT* Okey your code worked! i used $module->name not $module['name'], god damit! But thank you mate.